# How can I remove/disable an item in a DropdownButton's item list if it's selected on a second one (and vice-versa)?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown, dropdownbutton

I'm trying to make a pair of dropdown buttons that take their items from the same list, and selecting a value in one disables it in the other one, and vice versa (much like Translators software, or conversions, as this example is the second one).
I tried the `onChanged` methods but they only worked when checking the list AFTER changing its value (i.e, list 2's value was still showing up on list 1 until I changed list 1's value, and vice versa).

Here's the list

```
const List<String> tipolong = <String>['mi', 'km', 'fur', 'hm', 'ch', 'dam', 'rd', 'm', 'yd', 'ft', 'dm', 'in', 'cm', 'mm'];
```

And here are the two Dropdown buttons with their respective derivatives of said list

```
tipolong2 = List.from(tipolong);
tipolong3 = List.from(tipolong);

class _DropdownButtonState extends State<DropdownButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValueLength1,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          dropdownValueLength1 = newValue!;
          tipolong3 = List.from(tipolong);
          tipolong3.remove(dropdownValueLength1);
        });
      },
      items: tipolong2.map((dropdownValueLength1) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: dropdownValueLength1,
          child: Text(dropdownValueLength1),
        );
      }).toList(),    );
  }
}

class _DropdownButtonState2 extends State<DropdownButton2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValueLength2,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        // This is called when the user selects an item.
        setState(() {
          dropdownValueLength2 = newValue!;
          tipolong2 = List.from(tipolong);
          tipolong2.remove(dropdownValueLength2);
        });
      },
      items: tipolong3.map((dropdownValueLength2) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: dropdownValueLength2,
          child: Text(dropdownValueLength2),
        );
      }).toList(),    );
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that when I choose an item in the first list, it is removed or disabled from the second one, and vice versa? So far I've tried the onTap and `onChanged` methods but they both work only on my second time checking the list (the one that should disappear does so, but after I popped up the list for a second time instead of the first one).

Sorry if my explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that is user selected from 1st dropdown then disable 2nd dropdown and vice-a-versa

You can use `IgnorePointer` to achieve your functionality

1. 1st onChanged > Item Selected > store it in var A
2. Check var A is not empty > Disable 2nd DropDown and same for reverse